# Passing in private attributes into a utility function

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation, private-members

I have 3 classes with a merge operation that does identical operations with different arguments.

Here's the skeleton code of what I currently do:

```
class FirstClass:
  def __init__(self):
    # define constructor

  def merge(self, other):
    # merge other into self
    merge_util(src=other, dest=self)

class SecondClass:
  def __init__(self):
    # define constructor

  def merge(self, other):
    # merge other into self
    merge_util(src=other, dest=self)

# ThirdClass defined identically
```

`merge_util` is defined as follows:

```
def merge_util(src, dest):
  # merge src's private attributes (an array, list, and database table) into dest
```

The problem is this design seems to violate encapsulation. An external function is accessing private/protected attributes.

I've thought of 2 solutions:

1. Define `merge_util` as a method of each class, but then I'd be duplicating code for each class.
2. Use inheritance. These classes have few similarities otherwise hence why I didn't use inheritance from the beginning and want to avoid this.

Are there other approaches I can consider?

Answer (score 2):

what about composition?

define some kind of Merger with merge_util and pass it to your classes' constructors. calling it from inside a class won't violate encapsulation since your private attrs won't flow away to external function but internal Merger instance.

> ```
> class Merger:
>     def __init__(self):
>        # some settings here
>     
>     def merge_util(self, src, dest):
>        # your logic
>
> class FirstClass:
>   def __init__(self, ...):
>     self.merger = Merger()
>     # and so on
> ```

you can instantiate it inside or pass from outside to support modularity.

Comment: good idea, didn't think about composition

Comment: actually, if I make `Merger` only have static methods (since we don't really need instance methods here), how can I achieve composition in that case?

Comment: as long as I know it breaks nothing, you still will be able to call staticmethod on your Merger instance

Comment: if I understand you correct

Comment: so what I was envisioning is that instead of creating a `Merger` instance within `FirstClass`, we just call `Merge.merge_util` (and make `merge_util` a staticmethod). does that make sense? in that case I feel encapsulation is no longer maintained?

Comment: you are right, seems like we'll miss the main point here. but you still can call on Merger().merge_util(src, dst) with staticmethod to encapsulate your private attrs inside an instance rather than passing them to the external Merger class.

Comment: another option could be passing your attrs to init of Merger and don't change merge_util to staticmethod but using self-bound attributes instead